# p:dialog does not set properties to Entity

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have the following p:datatable that hold two buttons that call the View and the Add dialogs.
The problem is with the Add dialog, that does not seem to be setting properties to any of the Entity objects.

When I put a break on the save() method inside ChildrenController.java all values a 'null'.
I am using:
PrimeFaces 5.1 |
Mojarra 2.2.7 |
Glassfish 4.1 |

**ChildrenDataTable.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<h:form id="form1">
        <p:dataTable var="child" value="#{childrenController.children}"
                     scrollable="true" 
                     scrollHeight="500">

            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">First Name</f:facet>                    
                <h:outputText value="#{child.firstName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Last Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{child.lastName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Parent Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{child.parent.firstName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Parent Last Name</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{child.parent.lastName}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton update=":mainForm:form1:childDetail" 
                                 oncomplete="PF('childDialog').show()"
                                 process="@this"
                                 icon="ui-icon-search" 
                                 title="View">
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{child}"
                                                 target="#{childrenController.selectedChild}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:32px;text-align: center">
                <p:commandButton onclick="PF('childAddDialog').show()" 
                                 icon="ui-icon-person" 
                                 title="Add">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>


        <!-- Dialog for the View button-->
        <p:dialog header="Child Info" 
                  widgetVar="childDialog" 
                  modal="false" 
                  showEffect="fade" 
                  hideEffect="fade" 
                  resizable="false">
            <p:outputPanel id="childDetail" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid  columns="2" 
                              rendered="#{not empty childrenController.selectedChild}" 
                              columnClasses="label,value">
                    <h:outputText value="First Name:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{childrenController.selectedChild.firstName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Last Name:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{childrenController.selectedChild.lastName}" />

                    <h:outputText value="Birth Date:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{childrenController.selectedChild.dateOfBirth}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Medical Info:" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{childrenController.selectedChild.medicalInfo}" />
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>

        <!--Dialog for the Add button-->
        <p:dialog header="Register Child" 
                  widgetVar="childAddDialog" 
                  modal="false" 
                  showEffect="fade" 
                  hideEffect="fade" 
                  resizable="false">
            <p:outputPanel id="childRegister" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:panelGrid  columns="2" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Child info
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="First Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{childrenController.child.firstName}"
                                 required="true"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Last Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{childrenController.child.lastName}"
                                 required="true"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Birth Date:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{childrenController.child.dateOfBirth}"
                                 required="true"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Medical Info:"/>
                    <p:inputTextarea value="#{childrenController.child.medicalInfo}"
                                     rows="5" cols="30" counter="display" maxlength="128" 
                                     counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false"/>
                    <h:outputText id="display" />
                </p:panelGrid>

                <p:panelGrid  columns="2" >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Parent info
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="First Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{childrenController.parent.firstName}"
                                 required="true"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Last Name:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{childrenController.parent.lastName}"
                                 required="true"/>
                    <h:outputText value="Username:"/>
                    <h:inputText value="#{childrenController.user.username}"
                                 required="true"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Password1:"/>
                    <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{childrenController.password1}" 
                                match="pwd2" 
                                required="true"/>
                    <h:outputText value="Password2:"/>
                    <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{childrenController.user.password}" 
                                required="true"/>

                    <p:commandButton  actionListener="#{childrenController.save()}"
                                      value="Save"
                                      process="@this"
                                      oncomplete="childAddDialog.hide()"> 
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

**ChildrenController.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class ChildrenController implements Serializable{
    // This final string will be used to set the loginn role to parent
    private static final String parentRole = "parent";
    private String password1;


@EJB
private ChildEJB childEJB;
private Child currentChild;

private Child child = new Child();

@EJB
private ParentEJB parentEJB;
private Parent parent = new Parent();

@EJB
private RoleEJB roleEJB;
private Role role = new Role(parentRole);

@EJB
private UserEJB userEJB;
private User user = new User();

public Child getCurrentChild() {
    return currentChild;
}

public void setCurrentChild(Child currentChild) {
    this.currentChild = currentChild;
}

public Child getChild() {
    return child;
}

public void setChild(Child child) {
    this.child = child;
}

public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Parent parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Role getRole() {
    return role;
}

public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
}

public Child getSelectedChild() {
    return selectedChild;
}

public void setSelectedChild(Child selectedChild) {
    this.selectedChild = selectedChild;
}
private Child selectedChild;

public List<Child> getChildren() {
    return childEJB.findAll();
}

    public String getPassword1() {
    return password1;
}

public void setPassword1(String password1) {
    this.password1 = password1;
}

public void save(){
    // Map the parent to the child and vice verca
    parent.addChild(child);
    child.setParent(parent);

    // Persist the Parent
    parent = parentEJB.addNew(parent);

    // Persist the Child
    child = childEJB.addNew(child);

    // This will set the username for the parent role
    role.setUsername(user.getUsername());

    // This will set the role for the new username
    user.setRole(role);

    // This will map that the login belongs to a Parent
    user.setParent(parent);

    // Persist the new User
    user = userEJB.addNew(user);
}
```

}

**Stack Trace**

```
Warning:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB ParentEJB, method: public entity.Parent EJB.ParentEJB.addNew(entity.Parent)
Warning:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:698)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy250.addNew(Unknown Source)
    at EJB.__EJB31_Generated__ParentEJB__Intf____Bean__.addNew(Unknown Source)
    at mb.ChildrenController.save(ChildrenController.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [entity.Parent] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=lastName, rootBeanClass=class entity.Parent, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=firstName, rootBeanClass=class entity.Parent, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.validate(BeanValidationEventListener.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.beanvalidation.BeanValidationEventListener.onPreInsert(BeanValidationEventListener.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.preInsert(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:480)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:780)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:287)
    at EJB.ParentEJB.addNew(ParentEJB.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor168.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 54 more
```

Comment: The exception stacktrace indicates another layer. This line in the stacktrace : `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [entity.Parent]` could mean that you should be passing this detached entity `Parent` from your client application (the CDI bean) to an EJB with some `null` fields/properties which are being validated (using the `@NotNull` constraint) against `null` values by Hibernate Validator during persisting/merging that entity causing the mentioned exception. Make sure that none of the fields in the `Parent` entity violates the specified constraints.

Comment: When I place a breakpoint on the method save() and check all the values, they are all NULL. Every single value for Parent, Child and User are null its like nothing I have typed in the inputText fileds of the dialog are being set.

Comment: Why do you set those values directly to entity's properties? Instead you better declare individual properties of the required type in the managed bean, pass those property values to a target EJB as method parameters and perform business actions/operations in the EJB using the values of those properties/fields.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why I don't think that isn't the problem - the "private String password1" of the bean is also NULL. EDIT: The problem seems to be more general - the Dialog is not setting any fields in the bean regardless if its a field of an Entity or a simple String field.

Comment: You have set the `process` attribute of those two given `<p:commandButton>`s to `@this` - `process="@this"` which disallows the form to be processed along with those form fields. Consequently, you get `null` values for all of them in the bean, when anyone of those `<p:commandButton>`s is clicked. You had better either remove that `process` attribute from those command buttons or list the required form fields along with the `process` attribute whose values need to be set to the bean properties, when the corresponding command button is clicked.

Comment: I tried to completely remove "process" and removed all h:form tag from everywhere so its not caused by nested forms. Nothing is changing.

Comment: "*and removed all `h:form` tag from everywhere.*" I see only one  `<h:form>` in your current XHTML code snippet. Were you playing with nested forms in your real code or having multiple forms enclosing different components? Nesting of forms is not a legal HTML construct. It should have worked, if you had had exactly one `<h:form>`.

Comment: What I meant was that I removed all forms to make sure there is no nesting. It seems that this scenario is very specific as to where the form should be. To finally make it work I enclosed the dialog into a form and user process="@this :formName". Code looks like this:  <h:form id="formName">
        <p:dialog>
          <p:panelGrid>
           
          <p:commandButton process="@this :formName" ajax="false"      actionListener="#{bean.method()}"/>
          </p:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
</h:form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't `process` your components in your question's code. What you did there to fix the problem in your own answer is including your `form` in the list of `UIComponent`s to process. That means that JSF will not look at all your input components in your `form` and that's why it will not retrieve any values you entered in those fields to set them in your backing bean.

To get a better understanding of what process means, you may look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-process-and-update-attributes-of-primefaces).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by putting the p:commandButton inside the p:panelGrid of the dialog which makes absolutely no sense to me whatsovever ! Anyway here is how the dialog looks like:

```
<h:form id="formName">
        <p:dialog>
          <p:panelGrid>

          <p:commandButton process="@this :formName" ajax="false" actionListener="#{bean.method()}"/>
          </p:panelGrid>
        </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

EDIT: edited code to be more readable

Comment: Saying very genuinely : `process="@this :formName"` makes no sense, when `ajax` is set to `false`. Do you seriously understand what exactly you are doing in this code?